# Windows light stand-alone webserver that runs from USB stick

Tags: php, windows, sqlite, webserver

I'm looking for a Windows (XP/VISTA/7) stand-alone webserver that is small/light in size, can run php with sqlite3, and has a large userbase/online support.

So far I've tried Lighttpd and QuickPHP. Lighttpd has a large user base with loads of support, however I encountered many errors when calling some PDO functions, and it doesn't support fast-cgi on Windows.

QuickPHP passed my testing fine but it's a small project managed by one person on his free time with a very small userbase. I don't want to risk finding problems half-way into my project with no support from the author or access to the source code.

Any recommandations on what to try next?

Answer (score 0):

What about [XAMPP Lite](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#646)?

Comment: The download seems pretty large for a lite version but I'll start testing and see what I can strip from it to make it smaller. Thanks